# Access ADO: operation is not allowed when the object is closed error message

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using Access 2003 with a local table which will later be transferred and linked to a SQL Server 2008 table. I am using the following code but get the error: "Run-time error 3704: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed" on the cnn.Execute line.

```
sub test()
On Err GoTo Err_Sub
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim str As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    'Open a connection.
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection     
    cnn.ConnectionString = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & CurrentDb.Name & ";" & _
        "Persist Security Info=False"

    strSQL = Me.RecordSource
    str = Mid(strSQL, InStr(strSQL, "Where "))
    strSQL = "Update  myTable SET Active = False " & str

    Set rs = cnn.Execute(strSQL)

    If Not rs Is Nothing Then rs.Close

Exit_Sub:
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_Sub:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL` instead of declaring your `cnn` object.

Comment: It worked, but in doing so I wouldn't need the rs object. I am also not using ADO in the process.

Answer (score 18):

Ran into this error as well (in my case I am using a Stored Procedure to retrieve some information). I had made some changes which caused the execution to malfunction.

The error disappeared when I put `SET NOCOUNT ON` as the first statement of the Stored Procedure.

Comment: I just want you to know that 7 years in the future, someone would read this and find it helpful, thank you!

Comment: Thanks, @Seraphim !

Comment: I can do better than that - now 10 years on, and I found it helpful!

Comment: Seems that April is this answer's lucky month. Thanks, @AndyBrown

Answer (score 1):

Well that's simple. You need to add

```
cnn.Open
```

somewhere before cnn.Execute
also, don't forget to call

```
cnn.Close
Set cnn = nothing
```

before exiting from the sub

Comment: On cnn.open I am getting the error: "The database has been placed in a state by user 'Admin' on machine 'xxxx' that prevents it from being opened or locked."

Comment: @Rick Unlike DAO, you must save before using ADO with a MS Access DB.

Comment: Can't help. The causes of this error are very broad. From the simple table opened in design mode to concurrency issues. Searching for the first part of the error message could be a starting point.

Comment: @Remou What do you mean by saving?

Comment: @Rick If you have made any changes to any object including typing the code, you need to save (ctrl+S will often do) before running the code. Occasionally, you need to exit and re-open the db before running the code. It is easy to forget.

Comment: BTW, you can use `Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection`

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue as well. My error came up because I was naming one of the columns in the sql query 'Pit#'. I am fairly certain that it was the # that caused this error to happen for me. I hope this helps someone in the future.

Thanks -- Shell